# Extract IP and Cordinates from string in Java

Tags: java, regex

Hi I have a Java program which runs and finds my machines longitude and latitude coordinates, it outputs this as a long string show below,

> htt://maps.google.com/maps?q=52.258301,+-7.111900+(192.168.159.1Country:Ireland,City:Waterford-by
>   htt://www.javaquery.com)&iwloc=A&hl=en

What I am trying to do now is to only extract from this string: the IP address and the two coordinates, I have been successful in acquiring the IP address but cant seem to get the two coordinates.
The end result would hopefully be

> 192.168.159.1,52.258301,+-7.111900

So far ive used these expressions to get the IP address

```
(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

Which works just fine
and then attempted to get the coordinates using this

```
[0-9]+(\\.[0-9][0-9]?)?
```

but it only gets the first coordinate followed by it again

Thanks

Comment: htt instead of http, is that a typo?

Comment: What regex have you tried out ?

Comment: Editted to show what ive tried, and yes sorry its just a typo it really is http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this regex:

```
"(?<=\\?q=)([^(]*)\\(([\\d.]*)"
```

`group(1)` is `52.258301,+-7.111900+`

```
group(2) is the ip
```

**EDIT**  add codes for the regex matching/extraction

```
String regex = "(?<=\\?q=)([^(]*)\\(([\\d.]*)";
        String s = "htt://maps.google.com/maps?q=52.258301,+-7.111900+(192.168.159.1Country:Ireland,City:Waterford-by htt://www.javaquery.com)&iwloc=A&hl=en";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(2));
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
```

outputs:

```
192.168.159.1
52.258301,+-7.111900+
```

Comment: Thanks works great, one question the output is 52.258301,+-7.111900+(192.168.159.1 How would I make it so that it becomes (192.168.159.1+52.258301,+-7.111900

Comment: as I said, you just take `group(2)` and `group(1)`, you can arrange the order as your wish. also you can skip the `(` . or shell I provide codes for it??

Comment: Yes its just the output I get is then used further on in what im doing and it follows the format of IP then the Coordinates, so Im just unsure as to how to flip it around, sorry just never used regular expressions before this

Comment: Actually can't thank you enough for your help thanks a million, it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

An approach to extract the two coordinates, without regex, can be:

```
String str="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=52.258301,+-7.111900+(192.168.159.1Country:Ireland,City:Waterford-by htt://www.javaquery.com)&iwloc=A&hl=en";

int index_x=str.indexOf("?q=")+"?q=".length();
int index_x_end=str.indexOf(",");
int index_y=index_x_end+",".length();
int index_y_end=str.indexOf("+(");

System.out.println(str.substring(index_x, index_x_end));    //prints 52.258301
System.out.println(str.substring(index_y, index_y_end));    //prints +-7.111900
```